# Is there a better way to write this sentence in PHP / Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this kind of test again, and again, and I feel like there is a more elegant way to do it.

```
(isset($country['capital'])) ? $country['capital'] : null
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Your parentheses around the `isset()` are useless. Put the whole ternary operator between parentheses while nesting them or in string concatenation. But the null coalescing operator is the way to go if you have PHP7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `or` Operator In [Laravel Blade template](https://laravel-news.com/blade-or-operator)

```
$country['capital'] or null
```

And In php 7 you can use **Null coalescing operator**

```
$country['capital'] ?? null
```

[From PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar
>   for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with
>   isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL;
>   otherwise it returns its second operand.

Comment: That `or` won't do much. It's not Laravel, it's PHP (unless I'm really missing something about Laravel overloading PHP operators!?).

Comment: @deceze : I have cross checked `or` works for laravel not in `<?php ... ?>` tag, at my end.

Comment: What exactly does "in Laravel" mean then? Laravel is still written in PHP. Are you referring to some templating system? Then reference to documentation please.

Comment: @deceze :  I hope you aware about [this article](https://laravel-news.com/blade-or-operator)

Comment: So you're referring specifically to *Blade template syntax.* That's just one specific subcomponent of Laravel and not generally applicable to all "Laravel code".

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I should mention it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 7 you can do

```
$country['capital'] ?? null;
```

Comment: PHP 7.0 actually